# Wildfly-Swarm enable debug

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I've managed to convert my "war" application to a hollow jar.

My biggest issue is that even after following the documentation, still cannot enable debug mode (my desired port is 8784)

I am pretty sure that I am missing something but ... what?

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly-swarm.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <hollow>true</hollow>
                        <properties>
                            <swarm.debug.port>8784</swarm.debug.port>
                            <debug.port>8784</debug.port>
                            <swarm.debug.bootstrap>true</swarm.debug.bootstrap>
                            <java.net.preferIPv4Stack>true</java.net.preferIPv4Stack>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `swarm.sebug.port` property is only relevant when starting the application via the Swarm Maven plugin, or when using the Swarm Arquillian adapter. When starting the application using `java -jar myapp-swarm.jar`, you need to use the standard Java way of enabling remote debugging, i.e. something like `java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8784,server=y,suspend=n -jar myapp-swarm.jar`.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get it done via command line with java jar, but was trying with mvn wildflyswarm plugin and didn’t worked

Comment: Not sure if it even makes sense with the Maven plugin, if you're using a hollow JAR.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into:

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-1321
  or
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206848015-Breakpoints-not-working-when-debugging-simple-Java-EE-app-on-wildfly?page=1#community_comment_360000176459

The first link is the relevant one. I am including the second one just for further information if you are using IntelliJ for IDE.

Briefly, here is my pom configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>       
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>package</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <debugPort>5005</debugPort>
            <properties>
                <swarm.debug.port>5005</swarm.debug.port>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

After starting the application with the mvn swarm plugin, I am connecting with a remote debugger. 
**Good luck!**

**Edit (2019.05.31):**
My current setup for debugging in the pom.xml is the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            <jvmArgument>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArgument>
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Of course!
As I am using IntelliJ as IDE, I will explain it for my current setup.
The above configuration is in my pom file. 
I am starting the project with `mvn wildfly-swarm:run`
Then at some point, as described here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-1321
In the terminal you can see: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`
This is the point where you start your remote debugger:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html and attach it to localhost, with port 5005.
After you start your remote debugger the project continues to load.

Comment: Feel welcome to ask for further clarifications, just please specify on which part I should elaborate more. ^.^